# Are there any Java collection types that are unordered but sorted?

Tags: java, collections

Ordered collections in Java can be sorted or unsorted, but is it possible to have the reverse? Can unordered collections ever be sorted?

Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does "ordered" mean to you? If "ordered" means "maintaining insertion order" then "ordered" and "sorted" would be a contradiction in terms. If "ordered" means "maintaining any defined order" (as it usually does) then "unordered" and "sorted" are a contradiction in terms.

Comment: what for you is the difference between "ordered" and "sorted"?

Comment: Ordered - Elements maintained in terms of their insertion order. Sorted - Elements maintained in terms of their value.

Comment: If ordered means elements maintained in terms of their insertion order then any sorted collection happens to be unordered most of the time (except if you insert the elements in sorted order)

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to define what we mean by `ordered` and `sorted`.

I assume that:

- by `order` you mean insertion order
- by `sorted` you mean sorting according to a comparator

In that case, yes. A [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html)/`SortedSet` such as `TreeSet` does not remember the insert order but will keep (and return) the items offered in their natural order.